# iOS AdMob Reward Video - Implement rewarded video ad playing with "Skip after time" feature

Tags: ios, swift, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

My code is in swift 4,
As follows, it shows me Ads like, as shown in the 1st picture.

```
var rewardBasedVideo: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!
rewardBasedVideo = GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()        
rewardBasedVideo.delegate = self
rewardBasedVideo.load(GADRequest(),
                              withAdUnitID: GOOGLE_AD_UNIT_ID)
```

[image]

But I want to enable close Ad close button after some time. Or I want to show "Skip Ad" button instead of a close button 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also implemented the same and I do not think that there is a way around in the reward-based video ad. You can find other ad modules and they will provide the Skip Ad thing. But, in the reward-based video, you can not skip.

If you close it then the reward will not be paid. Sometimes, these are small, but sometimes up to a minute. There is no other way as of now.

We can see ads with skip after time feature in Google AdMob. But cannot achieve that programmatically. Maybe it is dependent on the creator of Ad.

Comment: is there a way, such that playing video ads with skip button using Google AdMob?

Comment: Please check https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start <- This link will tell you about all the ad formats they provide.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Rob

Comment: Do you know any Ads SDK that can fulfill my requirement?

Comment: Google it and you will get an option.

Comment: I think google also provides Ads with "Skip Ad" feature. But we can't do that by code. Creator of Ad might decide that.

Comment: I have seen a lot of ads, but never came across the one with skip ad option yet.

Comment: I saw that kind of ad first time, yesterday. With rewarded video ads